# Is there an image library in similar to Icon libraries?

Tags: html, css, icons, stylesheet

I have spent the last 2 weeks or so googling and asking around..with nothing found.
I'm looking for a referenceable image library, like an icon library. My thoughts are, if there are enough default images...it could be as useful and quick to implement images as it is to currently implement icons.
For example, Google Material design icons are referenced like

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">

     <i class="material-icons">
     train
     </i>
```

or IonIcon:

```
     <link 
     href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.1.2/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet">
     <i class="icon ion-md-heart"></i>
```

What I'm looking for is a image library like this. To allow for developers in my organization to link to default/stock images within their code with an icon tag.  Like this:

```
    <link 
     href="https://imagelibrary.com/here.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet">
     <i class="icon default-image1"></i>
```

I'm not a developer/coder, so perhaps there is something basic I'm missing, but this seems like a quicker way to link and change out default images rather than copying/finding a lengthy image url. (As long as the image file size is about the same as an icon.)

Thank you!